# define / declare variable in Scilab`

Tags: variables, declare, scilab

I would like to ask how I can define / declare a variable in Scilab.  In some PDFs that I read, it says that I can just type it in and Scilab will take care of the declaration.  Not so.  I want to set up a matrix equation of something like:

Ax + By + Cz = D

Mx + Ny + Pz = E

Rx + Sy + Tz = F

And then I want to get the general value of x, y, x in terms of A, B, C, D, E, F, M, N, P, R, S, T.  I remember this is possible with Matlab.  And later on, I want to plug in these values to get actual numbers.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Scilab is much more oriented at numerical computation than algebra solving, but you can still do it.

In your case you first should define the system in the form M1*x=M2, being M1 upper triangular.

I suggest you look at help for [solve()](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/solve.html) and [trianfml()](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/trianfml.html), there are nice examples.

After that you can evaluate the expressions giving any value you want for A, B, C, ..., using [evstr()](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/evstr.html)

For symbolic algebra, I recommend Wolfram mathematica, Maple, or Maxima (this last one is open-source like Scilab)

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is what I found.  SciLab requires "symbolic math toolbox" in order to do symbolic math.  the scimax/overload toolbox (by Calixte Denizet) can do that by integrating Maxima with SciLab.  however, it is only available on Linux/Unix OS.  another way to do it is the OVLD/SYM toolbox (by the deceased Jean-François Magni) which works with Windows (even Win 7).  however, support for this toolbox has ceased due to its author's demise.  the installation guide on spoken-tutorial.org no longer exists.  thus, I am left with using Maxima by itself to solve symbolic equations and calculus problems.